# Running rspec test twice when result is stochastic

Tags: rspec

I have an algorithm that works at a 99% confidence limit. So if I set up a test like this

```
let(:valid_input_signal) { randomly_generate_signal_plus_noise }
it { expect(my_detector(valid_input_signal).signal_present?).to be true }
```

it will fail 1% of the time.  I could write a test that runs my_detector on thousands of valid input signals and check it only fails 1% of the time, but this would take a long time to run, and the purpose of the test is not to check the algorithm works, but there have been no changes in the code that breaks the algorithm.

I think a valid way to achieve this is to run the above test a second time and if it passes, then give it a pass.  If it fails the second time, then give it a fail because the chance of it failing twice in a row assuming the base is correct is 1 in 10,000. Of course, this means 1 in 10,000 times the combined test will fail on a valid code base, but this is much better than at present, where 1 in 100 times the test fails.

So is there a way in rspec to do this, i.e. run a test a second time if it fails the first time, and only output a failure if it fails the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
describe '#my_decorator' do
  let(:valid_input_signal_1) { randomly_generate_signal_plus_noise }
  let(:valid_input_signal_2) { randomly_generate_signal_plus_noise }

  it 'should not fail twice in a row' do
    fail unless my_detector(valid_input_signal_1).signal_present? || my_detector(valid_input_signal_2).signal_present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> and the purpose of the test is not to check the algorithm works, but there have been no changes in the code that breaks the algorithm.

You can't test that in a randomly generated input data. Let's say you have a set of 100 valid_input_signals, and it fails on 5th one and it's ok. Somebody changes the algorithm, and it starts to pass on the 5th and fail on 17th. It still fails in 1% of the cases, but is it still correct?

How to continue from here is not obvious - it depends on what the algorithm does. Maybe you can extract some of the parts into single responsibility components and test them in isolation?

But maybe it's a legacy algorithm, and you need to cover it with specs as much as possible? If so - I'd trade the speed for coverage:

Generate 1000 signals, and save those which `my_detector(valid_input_signal).signal_present? == true`, save them in a file or something, and run specs against those, deterministic, inputs.

```
valid_inputs.each do |input| 
  expect(my_detector(input).signal_present?).to be true
end
```

Lets say 10 of those generated give `false`, inspect and confirm that it's a true negative (they're suppose to return false), save them in some other place and make specs for them as well:

```
invalid_inputs.each do |input| 
  expect(my_detector(input).signal_present?).to be false
end
```

Let's say (after manual inspection) only 8 of those were true negative, 2 left are supposed to return true, but return false - those could be bugs. Save them for later.

Are you happy with the coverage of 1000 samples? How long does it take to run in? Can you trade some of this time and increase the coverage to 10000 samples? 1 million? It's your choice.

At some point it'll make no sense to add more samples. Now you have crude coverage of the whole algorithm, and you can start some basic refactoring like [extract method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractFunction.html) or [name magic constants](https://refactoring.guru/replace-magic-number-with-symbolic-constant) and extract logical components (mentioned in par 2 of this answer). The X samples tests are temporary, they ensure (as much as they can with non-infinite sample size) that the behavior of the whole algorithm does not change while you chisel away parts of it that you understand better.

Comment: I've read about this approach somewhere, it's not mine invention, but I can't find it now. I think the author of the post where I read it called it a `skeleton test` but no meaningful search results for that. I'll post the link if more details come to my mind.

Comment: In my experience a test like I am using this can be useful to detect many types of changes that break the algorithm. It does not prove that all changes are correct, but that is not the purpose of it.  Still your discussion may be of interest, so I have upvoted it.

Comment: Yes - you are right. But randomness introduces flakiness, and this is a problem. It breaks the flow of you and other teams, and many flaky (false-negative) specs may cause people to start ignoring failing specs etc. It's a trade-off, it always is :)